# How connect Django administration to Firebase

Tags: django, firebase

I am trying to connect Django to Firebase, for moment i'm using Pyrebase and i install it with `pip install Pyrebase` and with that in my views.py of apps, i'm able to connect to my Firebase database and it work very fine.

How should i configure settings.py file to accept Firebase as default data base?
For moment i leave SQlite as default and i just access to my Firebase in views.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Regards./

Comment: I do not think it is possible like that : Firebase is not a database that you can plug to Django. You have to build query like that `db = firebase.database()
db.child("users").child("Morty")`

Comment: https://medium.com/@canadiyaman/how-to-use-firebase-with-django-project-34578516bafe